# areas where space is wasted in a typical disk filing system

Tags: architecture, filesystems

I am doing some revision for a System Architecture exam and came across this question from a past paper(below). I was not sure where to begin with it as it does not specify the type of filing system. The only thing I could think of when it comes to wasting space is the length of which can be variable.

Any help on the best way to tackle the below question, would be greatly appreciated.

```
Briefly discuss the areas where space is wasted in a typical disk filing
system, and indicate how a system designer may keep this to a
minimum. Note that, in this context, space wastage excludes user
actions, and is concerned principally with overheads within the system
itself.
```

Comment: It seems to be about a difference between real file size and its size on disk (which is integer number of blocks). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Space_management